# Objects modified when they are passed to a function as arguments in C++

Tags: c++, object, pointers, vector, arguments

I have the following simple vector class, where I can define vectors of different sizes and sum them; I have overloaded the + operator and include a simple data display method desplegar(); the class is defined as:

```
class Cvector{
   private:
   int dim;
   float * C;
public:
  Cvector(){};
  Cvector(int n){dim=n; C = new float[dim];};
  ~Cvector(){delete [] C;};
  int getdim(){return dim;};
  float getC(int i){
    if(i<dim && i>=0)
      return C[i];
    else
      return 0;
  };

  void setC(int i, float x){
    if(i<dim && i>=0)
        C[i]=x;
  }

  void desplegar(){
    cout<<"[ ";
    for(int i=0;i<dim;i++)
        cout<<getC(i)<<" ";
    cout<<" ]"<<endl;
  }

  Cvector operator + (Cvector);
};

Cvector Cvector::operator + (Cvector A){
    int n;
    if(A.getdim()>dim)
        n=A.getdim();
    else
        n=dim;

    Cvector temp(n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        temp.setC(i,getC(i)+A.getC(i));
    return temp;
}
```

When I run the following code, everything works fine:

```
Cvector X(2);
Cvector Y(3);
```

defines the objects of dimension 2 and 3

```
X.setC(0,1);
X.setC(1,4);

Y.setC(0,0);
Y.setC(1,6);
Y.setC(2,9);
```

adds the corresponding values to each dimension (2 for X and 3 for Y)

```
X.desplegar();
Y.desplegar();

Cvector T=Y+X;
T.desplegar();
```

Everything is displayed correctly up til here, T displays the sum of vector Y and vector X, which is what I want. But when I run

```
X.desplegar();
```

it only displays unrelated data from memory, it seems that object X is modified when it is passed as an argument to operator +, why is this so? If I instead use pointers to the objects this does not happen, but it does not seem intuitive for this to happen.

can anyone comment?

Comment: *Possibly* you need to implement `operator=` or that assignment may mess up one of your incoming operands. Also, you really should pass `const` references rather than pass by value and learn about the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C++_programming)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you overload the `operator +` with argument pass-by-value, the copy constructor is invoked to instantiate a temporary object. By default, the copy constructor is a bitwise copy of the original object. And just before the method returns, the destructor, which is user-defined, is invoked on the temp object, where the underlying storage is deallocated.

To correct the code, please define the copy constructor yourself or pass the argument by reference.

Please always remember the [rule-of-three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29), that is when you've defined any of destructor, copy constructor, and assignment operator, please consider also define the others among these three.

Comment: Thanks, this makes complete sense!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `operator+`.

```
Cvector Cvector::operator + (Cvector A)
```

Here, you are passing the second operand (which, in your case is `X`) by making a *copy* of it. This copy (`A`) will have it's `C` pointer pointing to the same memory as your `X` vector:

```
Cvector T=Y+X;
```

In the end of the `operator+`, the copy will get destroyed, the destructor will be called, and the memory will be freed. Since this memory is shared by the copy of `X`, and `X` itself, you will have garbage. Change your `operator+` so it takes a reference and everything will work fine:

```
Cvector Cvector::operator + ( const Cvector & A )
```

Note that it is also a good idea to implement a copy constructor.

Comment: Thanks, is it necessary to make it a const?

Comment: @user3035350, no it isn't

Answer (score 0):

You copy vectors incorrectly. *temp* has its destructor automatically invoked at the end of *operator+*, causing T to have a dangling pointer. You might be doing something similar to X, it's hard to tell without looking at the complete program.

Answer (score 0):

Cvector doesn't have a copy constructor, so the default one will be generated:

```
Cvector::Cvector(Cvector const & original)
  : dim(original.dim), C(original.C)
{}
```

this does a *shallow* copy, that is, you now have two objects with the same C pointer.

So, when you *copy* X as the argument to any function, this happens:

```
Cvector x;
// populate X
// now call this:
void foo(Cvector y) { // y is created as a copy of x
} // y is destroyed
```

when the copied argument is destroyed, it deletes C, which is *shared* with the original.

---

These changes should be made:

1. write proper a copy constructor and assignment operator, that perform a deep copy (this will stop copies from breaking the original object when destroyed)
2. pass arguments by const reference when you're not changing them

Comment: Cop constructor can solve it, but passing by reference is the quickest way to do so!

Comment: The copy constructor should be added _anyway_, because this code is terribly fragile without it.